# How can I print more than 100 documents from mongoDB collection with promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I what to just print all items from a collection. I am using this code and is working fine with less then 100 items in the collection .

When I have more is just printing:

```
ITEMS: undefined
1
ITEMS: undefined
2
.....
ITEMS: undefined
99
ITEMS: undefined
100
ITEMS: undefined
```

> C:\Users\rmuntean\Documents\Automatizare\NodeJS\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:98
>       process.nextTick(function() { throw err; });
>
> TypeError: callback is not a function

I tried also toArray and is same problem.

The Code without promises is working fine and I can print all items.

```js
var bluebird = require('bluebird');
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var MongoCollection = require('mongodb').Collection;

bluebird.promisifyAll(require('mongodb'));

const connection = "mongodb://localhost:27017/test";

var cc = 0;
var theDb
var theCollection

MongoClient.connectAsync(connection)
  .then(function(db) {
    theDb = db;
    return theDb.collectionAsync("test_array");
  })
  .then(function(collection) {
    theCollection = collection;
    return theCollection.findAsync({});
  })
  .then(function(cursor) {
    cursor.forEach((err, items) => {
      console.log("ITEMS:", items);
      cc++
      console.log(cc);
    });
  })
  .finally(() => {
    theDb.close()
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
    err(500);
  });
```

I am using:

```
"mongodb": "^2.2.12",
"bluebird": "^3.4.6",
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `cursor.forEach((err, items)`  your not returning anything here, so your finally is getting called straight away.  You could wrap the forEach inside a Promise, as I beleive when all items done `items` will be false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your forEach is not returning a promise, `finally` is getting called instantly, IOW: `theDb.close()` is getting called before you've even had chance to iterate the result.  This explains the `undefined`.

So you need to control when the forEach has finished,  I've not used monogoDb, but looking at docs, if the doc is empty, it means end of list.

With promises, always remember from inside another `then` method, if you don't return a Promise, the next `then` / `finally` etc will get called without waiting, you basically have broken the promise chain.

So hopefully the following will help.

```
.then(function(cursor) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    cursor.forEach((err, items) => {
      if (err) return reject(err);
      if (!items) return resolve(); //no more items
      console.log("ITEMS:", items);
      cc++
      console.log(cc);
    });
  });
})
```

Comment: Thank you, I used your advice and code and is working :

 .then(function(cursor) {
              return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                cursor.each((err,items) => {
                  if (cursor.isClosed()) return resolve();
                  console.log("ITEMS:", items);
                  cc++
                  console.log(cc);
                });
              });
            })